# Sending data from Django application to another Python script

Tags: python, django, post

I have a Django application where some data can be saved on my database using a form.

I would like to create a Python script that, as soon as a new record is created, sends that data to an external Python script as json, and this external Python script should perform some operation with this data.

This question is not about code, but i'm trying to be as specific as possible: is there a way to create a system that sends data to another system? In this case the data i need to send is the records submitted from forms of my Django app to another Python script. I'm supposing that the external script should be listening to some sort of URL, maybe? How could i accomplish this? Maybe with Webhooks?

Comment: Why does this other script need to be "external"? Why can't you import it and run it in your Django app?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Well, the problem is that it would be an engine with a lot of functionalities and it could get quite complicated with time, so i can't do everything it would be supposed to do with simple Django and nothing else

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If the script is in Python, you can import and call it from your Django view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman it is not a function that i would call every tot time, it's a python application that i'm hosting on a different server, that will run endlessly

Comment: You need to be clearer about what you're asking. What kind of application is it? How does it take input? How is it running endlessly?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, basically it's an application that would do some operations with external APIs, Once the data is received from Django in any way, it should take this data and perform operation with those APIs. How does it take input? It's what i tried to ask in the question, maybe with a system that is listening to an URL, my Django client will send data to that URL and the Python application will receive that data

Comment: Argh. If the application already exists, then it must be taking input in some way. But if it's not already a complete application, I still don't understand why you wouldn't just integrate it directly into your Django app. Django is already "a system that is listening to a URL". Unless you are looking to create a microservices architecture.

Comment: It does not exist yet, the input should be the data sent from Django, i mean, when it receives json data it will use that data to perform operation, yes it would be sort of a microservice architecture

Comment: i used to come across this problem before, my company decided to put the external script into an api(made from flask - it's simple and lightweight) and just call the flask api from out django app with the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest following:

Your separate application establishes only one very simnple interface, that your django application can use.

The only purpose is to tell your application, that there is data ready to fetch.

You could implement this via a simple TCP or UDP socket or via one dedicated http request. It doesn't really matter.

Whenever your application gets notified that there are things to do it will connect via dedicated django views to ask what data can be fetched and fetch the data.
you could use the django rest frame work.

The whole point.

A django server is intended to provide data and to allow uploading data.
Let your special application use django viewa to fetch and process data.

Either your application polls periodically or if your app really has to react immediately implement one simple way, that allows django to notify your application.

The external application can use the requests library ( https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/ ) in particular requests.session to connect to your django server, to authenticate, fetch the data and process it.

Your Django server has just to expose a url / a view that allows to fetch all the data. can be a hand coded view or something encoded with the django rest framework. A typical exchange format would be json, but it's entirely up to you. Don't forget to secure this urls such, that only authorized users can connect to it and fetch data.

Now the question is how to trigger the action. THis depends on many things. Does you external server just wait for new data from one django server or from multiple ones?

You could just use the http.server (threaded server) in your external program. It would listen to external requests and get for example the url of the django server to connect to and one id for the data to fetch and process.
Depending on the duration of the processing the external program would probably immediately acknowledge the request but the information into a queue and process as soon as a worker is available. All this is difficult to say without knowing all details, the run times, complexity and infra structure and the related security aspects.

Comment: Is there some sort of dedicated modules that i can use for this? Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: enhanced my answer a little.

Comment: This if air enoug. Thank you :)